# Can't remove item from a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I've got the list:

```
['ammassuladu', 'papa', 'tintola (Alghero)', 'viri, bмvere', "'acha", "'arzola", "'ccetta", "'eneru", "'enucru", "'enucr u", "'erru", "'estire", "'estire", "'ichu", "'ichumurisca", "'idru", "'inu", 'cherjere', 'mariane', 'mrexаni', 'matxoni (Alghero)', 'bolta, borta', 'cociula', 'remщliu', 'molinana', 'vтrtitxe (Alghero)', 'votаi,  botаre,  votаre', 'trimizon e', 'vulcаnu, vurcanu', 'sboriаi,  ibboidare,  sbuidаi', 'txapar (Alghero), cavт (Tabarchino)', 'taffaranu, tafferanu', 'safiru', 'butirera,  butirrera, bituиra', 'tzintzalu,  tzintzula,  tintula', 'sмnciu, sinsulu, sintzu, sintzula', 'marr a', 'marrare', 'zia', 'tia', 'tzia, cia', 'zizм', 'lamparaxu', 'orgiali, orxali,  orxabi', 'zingaru, zinganu', 'ziu', 't io', 'tiu, tziu', 'tuche, tughe', 'bachiаna, baghiana, bagiana, baiana, vagghiana', 'citiri (stare zitto)', 'carabassa',  'sщcura (Alghero)', 'zucchinu', 'cruccuriga', 'mтidare,  muidare,  muitare']
```

My tasks: delete words in parentheses and divide items which include commas to separate words.

I us for it a simple cycle(dialettando_tokens is the list):

```
string = " ".join(dialettando_tokens)
dialettando = string.split()
for word in dialettando:
    if '(' in word or ')' in word:
        dialettando.remove(word)
    elif ',' in word:
        dialettando.remove(word)
        dialettando.append(word[:-1]) 

print(dialettando)
```

Output:

```
['ammassuladu', 'papa', 'tintola', 'viri,', 'bмvere', "'acha", "'arzola", "'ccetta", "'eneru", "'enucru", "'enucru", "'e rru", "'estire", "'estire", "'ichu", "'ichumurisca", "'idru", "'inu", 'cherjere', 'mariane', 'mrexаni', 'matxoni', 'bolt a,', 'borta', 'cociula', 'remщliu', 'molinana', 'vтrtitxe', 'votаi,', 'votаre', 'trimizone', 'vurcanu', 'ibboidare,', 's buidаi', 'txapar', 'cavт', 'taffaranu,', 'tafferanu', 'safiru', 'butirrera,', 'bituиra', 'tzintzula,', 'tintula', 'sinsu lu,', 'sintzula', 'marra', 'marrare', 'zia', 'tia', 'cia', 'zizм', 'lamparaxu', 'orxali,', 'orxabi', 'zinganu', 'ziu', ' tio', 'tziu', 'tughe', 'baghiana,', 'baiana,', 'vagghiana', 'citiri', **'zitto)'**, 'carabassa', 'sщcura', 'zucchinu', 'cruc curiga', 'muidare,', 'muitare', 'botаre', 'vulcаnu', 'sboriаi', 'butirera', 'tzintzalu', 'sмnciu', 'sintzu', 'tzia', 'or giali', 'zingaru', 'tiu', 'tuche', 'bachiаna', 'bagiana', 'mтidare']
```

AS you can see it deleted all unnecessary items except 'zitto)' and I don't know why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list `dialettando` is modified while iterating over it. This would give you unexpected result.

Instead, iterate over its copy like this:

```
for word in dialettando[:]:
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* remove items from a list while iterating over it.  But this syntax is not documented and is not guaranteed to be portable.  But generally, if you are iterating over a list and want to remove the current element, your "current" element becomes the element after the one you removed.  Here's what you can do to make it work without making a copy of the list:

```
i = 0
while i < len(myList):
    if myList[i] matches some criteria for deletion:
         myList.remove(myList[i])
    else:
        i += 1
```